# R shiny: Hide NA before using plot click to return values in conditional panel

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am using plot_click to interrogate a graph in Shiny and would like the conditional panel to show 2 bits of information. However at the moment, the conditional panel shows 'NA' until i perform the plot click, how do i make this disappear?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
# make some data
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2),x=c(33,7),y=c(50,16),name=c("Tom","Bill"),link=c("https://mylink.com","https://anotherlink.com"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Shiny app

ui <- basicPage(
    plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selection"),
  conditionalPanel("!is.na(output.nametext)",
                   h4(textOutput("nametext")),
                   h4(textOutput("urltext")))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
      geom_point()+
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 68))+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 52.5))
  })

  output$selection <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(df, input$plot_click)
  })

  info <- reactive({

    t <- as.data.frame(nearPoints(df, input$plot_click))
    s <- t[1,4]
    u <- t[1,5]
    list(s=s,u=u)

  })

  output$nametext <- renderText({info()$s})
  output$urltext <- renderText({info()$u})
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

in the conditionalPanel in the UI, i've tried `!is.na(output.nametext)`, `output.nametext != null`, `output.nametext==true`, `plot_click==true`, `plot_click!=null` and more. None of them remove the NA that exists before i perform the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to simply use:

```
  output$nametext <- renderText({
    if(!is.na(info()$s)){
      info()$s      
    }
  })
```

You could also use the space to inform the user he should click a point to see information:

```
  output$urltext <- renderText({
    if(!is.na(info()$s)){
      info()$u
    }else{
      print("Click on a point to get additional information")
    }
  })
```

Comment: well now, why didn't i think of the old 'is.na' within the renderText. Great stuff, will accept when it allows me in a few mins

Comment: could I ask, what do you make of the way i've extracted the info from nearPoints for this task? i struggled on this for quite a while, surprised i couldn't simply access it with the $ notation (like input$plot_click$x)

Comment: hmm,...how about this: `click <- nearPoints(df, input$plot_click);
      list(name = click$name[1], link = click$link[1])`